# Near Field Communication Tag Reading Capability not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc

I'm fairly new to iOS development, and I have a project that required CoreNFC. I'm trying to add the capability to my project, however it's not showing up in the list of capabilities. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to add the "Near Field Communication Tag Reading" capability to an iOS project:

1. Select the project
2. Select the target
3. Select "Signing and Capabilities"
4. Choose an appropriate team and bundle identifier. Leaving the team as "None" will result in errors trying to add the capability.
5. Click on "+ Capability"
6. Double-click on the "Near Field Communication Tag Reading" capability in the Capabilities window to add it to the target.

[image]

Comment: I already have a Team selected (it's a Personal Team), and the bundle identifier, do I need to have an account that has enrolled in Apple's Developer Program (the 99$ one)?

Comment: I'm not sure about the need for a paid account. Are you saying that the NFC Tag Reading capability doesn't appear in the Capabilities screen at step 6? Since testing NFC will require testing with real iOS devices, you are going to need a paid account any way.

Comment: I already have a real iOS device, and I've never paid extra to test on it, I've always used my personal account. When I select None for step 4, the NFC Tag Reading Capability appears, but then it says the app requires signing, so then I select my personal account and it says there's an error, until i remove the NFC capability, it works then but it doesn't appear on the menu whenever I have my personal account selected.

Comment: I only have a paid account so I can't verify what happens with a free account. I do know that with a paid account the NFC capability works just fine.